# In Raw Socket programming on Linux, how can I prevent the underlying OS from responding to an incoming packet?

Tags: linux, raw-sockets

I am sending SYN packets using raw sockets in Linux. The response(SYN+ACK) is being intercepted by the OS and it is responding with a RST. I would like to prevent the OS from intercepting this packet, and let it be handled by my application. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a rule in IPtables to filter outgoing RST packets.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

Don't forget to disable it later!
Have fun.